# re-creating schema.db from changed db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

In my endless stupidness I changed the mysql db using mysql and not migrations, so now the db is out of sync with migration.

my question is, if it's possible to generate the missing migrations (step) and a new schema.db without loosing data and the changes* in the db?

*changes like adding tables, columns.

thx

Answer (score 1):

As far as recreating your migrations, you're out of luck but you can recreate the schema

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

If you go this route, when creating a new db (for a new environment etc...) you'll want to do

```
RAILS_ENV=some_env rake db:schema:load # specify the env if not development
```

instead of

```
rake db:migrate
```

since your migrations do not align with the current schema.

Be careful when running `schema:load` as it recreates the db from scratch. i.e. you'll lose all data.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to create the missing migrations. You can fix your local dev database by adding the timestamps to the `schema_migrations` table manually. That is the consequence of changing your schema by hand.

Also make sure that `rake db:migrate:reset` (drop all tables and migrate from scratch) will produce the same `db/schema.rb` as `rake db:schema:dump` would. Any change in the database schema must be automated by a migration.

The problem with rake `db:schema:load` is that it will forcefully create the tables.

Comment: yes but this would result in a complete loss of table data, right?!

Comment: yes, it will only create the tables from scratch but not the data. So the alternative is to first export your data somewhere and then do reset so that later you again load it.